# Reading a particular graph from file

Tags: python, graph, networkx, edge-list

I have to read and create a graph with networkx using an existent .txt file.

The txt file starts with:

```
% asym posweighted
% 28236 1574 1574
1 2 1
1 3 7
4 5 3
6 7 5
6 8 14137
9 10 8
11 2 8
12 5 413
13 14 2
13 15 2
16 17 2
18 5 416
18 19 2
20 21 8
20 22 11
20 23 1
24 22 96
25 2 41
....
```

I use this python code

```
 import networkx as nx
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


 file = open("us-usairport.txt","rb")
 grafo = nx.read_weighted_edgelist(file,,create_using=nx.Graph(),nodetype 
       = int)
 print(nx.info(grafo))
 nx.draw(grafo)
 plt.show()
 file.close()
```

I receive this error message:
     TypeError: Failed to convert nodes %,asym to type .

Using a delimiter=',' my graph has 0 nodes and 0 edges and plots a blank page.
Where is the problem?

Comment: It seems that the first 2 lines are comments. `nx.read_weighted_edgelist` allows you to specify the comment char (default is `#`).
`grafo = nx.read_weighted_edgelist(file,,create_using=nx.Graph(),nodetype  = int, comments = '%' )` should solve it
check out the documentation [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_weighted_edgelist.html)